# "Could not get any response" in Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, postman

I am learning ASP.NET Core. The server I am using for this purpose is Postman, which I import a JSON file to from disc. The code for the API is written in Visual Studio and is compiled error-free.
When I send a GET request in Postman, I get this error: "Could not get any response". 
To solve this I made changes in the setting (see the attached images), but it was not the solution. Could you please me with this?
[image] [image]

This is an screenshot showing the GET request and the error I get:[image]

The code for the Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CityInfo.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/cities")]
    public class CitiesController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetCities()
        {
            return Ok(CitiesDataStore.Current.Cities);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetCity(int id)
        {
            var cityToReturn = CitiesDataStore.Current.Cities.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            //);
            if (cityToReturn == null)
                return NotFound();
            else
                return Ok(cityToReturn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the postman request and the API endpoint (including the route)?

Comment: I have added a screenshot showing the GET request.
(Since I am new to this, I might misunderstand terms and phrases. Please tell me if I should provide more info).

Comment: consider a look in the console of the server (Visual Studio - Output window) if there is a message for a request

Comment: @LHK1337CodingCorner
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.5\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\khba\source\repos\CityInfo\CityInfo.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\CityInfo.API.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.5\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just

Comment: Could you please also include a screenshot of the C# action that you're trying to hit?

Comment: @ChristopherLake
I've just added the code for the controller, too.

Comment: Are you able to access the endpoint through your browser instead of Postman?

Comment: @MaYaNicolson if this is all you got then your server didn&#39;t start listening on any address:port and/or postman can&#39;t reach the it.  After the server init phase there should be an output like: &quot;starting server on 0.0.0.0:5000&quot; (like not equal!)

Comment: No I am not able to access it via my browser either.@ChristopherLake

The output console shows a very long text, mainly is the repetition of what I have copied here.@LHK1337CodingCorner

Comment: Okay so at least we know the issue doesn't lie with Postman. I see you have a lot of requests in your collection... do _any_ of them work? I hate to ask this but are you sure that the program is running and the port is correct?

Comment: The program is built error-free. When I run the IIS express, in the browser console I get these messages:
Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that error. You may have to fix that issue first. Hopefully someone can assist you.

Comment: What is **When I run the IIS express, in the browser console I get these messages: Exception in onResRdy**? Could you share us a screen shot about the result from web browser? I am wondering why it returned this when you request this api.

Comment: Thank you everybody for cooperation. I finally solved the issue by adding **.AddMvc()** to **ConfigureSevices** in **Startip.cs**

Comment: I was facing a similar situation: I was able to access via browser but couldn't via Postman. The solution was to disable "SSL certificate verification" in Postman > Settings > General

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was having the same problem. It is my first time using asp net core to build a web api and was struggling with this same issue.

### I've solved this way:

use `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` to build the certificate.
Then use `dotnet run`

To fix in postman go to the Settings -> General and turn off SSL certificate verification.

Hope it helps you.

Found out the answer in this video: [ASP .NET Core - Fix Problem Postman cannot access due to SSL Certificate Error by CMVDev](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmTIEn7M6oQ)